# Kubernetes Networking connect local/container

Tags: networking, kubernetes, flannel, calico

I'm a Developer going up the learning curve to become more DevOps.

I'm building a Kubernetes cluster. I'd like to be able to 'directly' connect to pods. I don't want to be load balanced through a Service, I want to be able to connect to individual pods.

I'm reading up about networking, but feel overwhelmed. I'll get the answer myself when I've grokked the details, but before then is there any expert that can answer:

Is there any kubernetes networking option that will allow me to talk TCP/IP from my local directly to individual pods?

I am absolutely open to running something locally to achieve this. I don't really care if its overlay or not (no latency requirements). I'm thinking I can run Calico on the Cluster, Bird on my Machine. Is this true? Has anyone done anything similar?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options for this.

If you want to connect to one particular pod you can simply `kubectl port-forward` which will forward local port to pods port.

If you need full network connectivity, depending on how you provisioned the cluster, you can actually make your pc a part of the same overlay network as your kubernetes cluster (I do something like that using weave net).

All in all, apart of the port-forward solution, it's more of a generic networking issue rather than kubernetes in particular. But then again, if you manage to become peer in your overlay, you still have the issu of service discovery to crack, if you dont want to use services...

Comment: Much appreciated. I'm trying to understand how you did this. Could you give me some links/terms to google?

Answer (score 0):

While kubectl port-forward (like this command : kubectl port-forward pod/my-pod 8080:80)and kubectl proxy are viable options, utilizing a NodePort Service or a LoadBalancer Service is the more robust and scalable approach for directly accessing individual pods from your local machine over TCP/IP. NodePort Services assign a port on each worker node's IP, allowing you to access pods using :. LoadBalancer Services provision an external load balancer that forwards traffic to pods, enabling access via the load balancer's external IP. These service types offer a persistent and production-ready solution for exposing pods to external traffic.